# STL functions not working in vscode for my Mac

Tags: c++, function, visual-studio-code, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

void reverseSentence(string s)
{
    stack<int> st;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        string word = "";
        while (s[i] != ' ' && i < s.length())
        {
            word += s[i];
            i++;
        }
        st.push(word);
    }
    while (!st.empty())
    {
        cout << st.top() << " ";
        st.pop();
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main()
{
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    reverseSentence(s);
    return 0;
}
```

[The image shows the error displayed in the push(), pop(), empty() functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN6NY.png)
I am currently using MacOS Ventura 13.1 , it would be great if anyone could help.

Since the functions aren't working, I cannot use the STL templates for my codes.

Comment: Why are you creating a `stack` of `int`s if you want to put `string`s on it?

Comment: FYI: an alternative way how to post a textual error is as text.

Comment: Unrelated, the whitespace separation in your sentence reversal is destined to fail regardless. `cin >> s;`, the source of your string input, is only going to be a single char sequence anyway (with no whitespace).

Comment: Also unrelated : stop using `using namespace std;`. Just using namespaces like that can/will in bigger projects lead to nameclashes or surprising name lookups.  Just learn to type `std::` in front of standard libary types. imagine if you include someone elses header file that also has a string class, or a min function (the last one for example is true for the windows.h header).

Answer (score 1):

This is not working because you are creating `stack<int>` and you are pushing `string`, templates are compile time evaluated and compiler generate code based on the type you provided. so you are creating stack with `int` and you are pushing `string` so `stack<int>` does not have `push` for `string`. Change`stack<int>` to `stack<string>`.